# How to add a combobox to the cell of the QtTreePropertyBrowser class?

Tags: c++, qt

Someone knows how to add a combobox to the cell of the QtTreePropertyBrowser class?Similar as the property view dock in Qt Designer.

Answer (score 0):

You should make children of that class and define your own createEditor()

```
 QWidget * MyPropertyBrowser::createEditor ( QtProperty * property, QWidget * parent )  
{
QComboBox* combo = new QComboBox( parent );
// Setup combo here
return combo
}
```

Comment: Hmm, thank you very much, i think that works. And actually today i just got the solution to solve this problem, i read some blogs and tried QtEnumPropertyManager this class, then finally i got the combobox into the cell of QtTreePropertyBrowser, just put QStringList to the enumManager. Anyway, thank you very much.